# How to get target route in ng2 guard canActivate?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-guards

How can I get the route which the user is trying to open within an canActivate guard in angular 2?

How can I make the guard watch for every route parameter change eg. a change of the id within the route?

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Observer, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class RightsGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private route: ActivatedRoute
      // private state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ) { }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      var targetUrl = ???
      // var targetUrl = this.router.url // is showing previous url?
      return true;
    }
}
```

Suggested answer in [Angular 2 get current route in guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747246/angular-2-get-current-route-in-guard) using `private state: RouterStateSnapshot`
  and then `this.route.url` does not work for me, since it throws an DI error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error
Error: DI Error
```

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work, however route and state must not be injected in the constructor since this causes errors.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
  console.log("route-access",state);
}
```

However this results in the problem that the guard is only called once for each route. For changes of route parameters like :id the guard is not being invoked. But this seems to correlate with a bug in the 3.2 router:

- [Calling angular2 route guard multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692497/calling-angular2-route-guard-multiple-times/40693108#40693108)
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12851