# Get target route URL in CanActivate guard Lazy load modules Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm trying to get the target URL in canActivate guard but unable to do so. I've configured `preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules` in `RouterModule.forRoot` when i use `ActivatedRoute` its url property doesn't contain path.
here's both of my module:

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SiteLayoutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules } 
    ),
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuardAuthService, LoginService, SharedService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

user.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'user',
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'create', pathMatch: 'full' },
            {
                path: 'create', component: CreateComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] //need activated route in this guard
            },
            { path: ':id/edit', component: CreateComponent },
            { path: 'list', component: UserListComponent }
        ],

    },
    {
        path: 'role',
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'create', pathMatch: 'full' },
            {
                path: 'create', component: RoleComponent,
                resolve: {
                    Modules: RolesResolver
                }
            },
            {
                path: ':id/edit', component: RoleComponent,
                resolve: {
                    Modules: RolesResolver,
                }
            },
            { path: 'list', component: RoleListComponent },
        ],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CreateComponent,
        RoleComponent,
        UserListComponent,
        RoleListComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(
            appRoutes
        )
    ],
    providers: [RouteGuard, UserService, RoleService, RolesResolver],
})
export class UserModule { }
```

i need activated route in RouteGuard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    console.log("route-access", state);
}
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171356/how-to-get-target-route-in-ng2-guard-canactivate) answer.

Comment: already tried it gives:
StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRouteSnapshot]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!

Comment: do you import it like this?
`import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate,  RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
`

Comment: yes, here's my import for RouteGuard:

import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRoute, CanActivateChild, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

Comment: Its really strange, couse this works for me. What Angular version are you using? Is this produced with Angular 5?

Comment: Yes man I'm using angular 5 and i'm stuck for hours due to this.

Comment: this is really strange. Could you please extend your question with the full implementation of the RouteGuard service?

Comment: Hey @ForestG thanks there was an issue in my canActivate method. I injected ActivatedRouteSnapshot provider in service constructor instead of canActivate. Cheers dude :)